# java.lang.NullPointerException when using Java with Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, nullpointerexception, jruby

I am trying to call a ruby function in java. but I got a `NullPointerException` when I run the program.
Here is my java code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MyProgram
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException 
    {
        try
        {
            ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine rbEngine = mgr.getEngineByExtension("rb");

            InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("src/myruby.rb");
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            rbEngine.eval(reader);
            Invocable invocableEngine = (Invocable)rbEngine;

            if (invocableEngine != null)
            {
                int set = (Integer) invocableEngine.invokeFunction("myfunc",6,6);
            }

        }
        catch (ScriptException e)
        {
            System.out.println("\nScriptException = "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the myruby.rb file contains

```
def myfunc(a,b)
  f=a+b
  return f
end
```

The Error I am getting is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at MyProgram.main(MyProgram.java:22)
```

Please help me to find the problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in catch please use `e.printStackTrace()` and after then share the exception.I guess your `ScriptEngineManager mgr` object is null and it is throwing exception at `mgr.getEngineByExtension("rb");`

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("src/myruby.rb");
```

Here, `is` is null.

Try an absolute path to open your file.

If your file is found, then there is a problem with the `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream`.

Comment: absolute path? You mean full path of that file?

Answer (score 0):

As LaGrandMere said in his answer `is` is null here.

It is null because `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream` is not able to find the resource specified. 
`ClassLoader` looks for the resource in the `classpath` specified. 
 To get this resource available, add `myruby.rb` in your class path.

Hope this helps !!